# MIL-Spec Differences

Tags: capacitor, components

Recently I was following an online project guide, and ordered many components online.

One of the components, a 0.10uF capacitor with 50V rating, returned some results which said they were "MIL" rated.

The stats appeared the same between the "MIL-Spec" and regular capacitors, same heat rating, etc. The MIL-Spec capacitors seemed to contain lead, but that was the only discernible difference, other than shape (square instead of rounded). They weren't really any more expensive when buying only a few.

At the time I placed my order, the MIL-Spec caps were all that was in stock for my project, so I ordered them. They came with a certificate that they were MIL rated, from the original manufacturer, including military identification numbers, etc.

Example:

MIL-Spec: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/kemet-mil/CK05BX104K/1001-2004-MIL/2397486

Standard: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-bc-components/K104K10X7RF53L2/K104K10X7RF53L2-ND/2820500

What is the real difference between MIL-Spec components and regular components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main differences are.

1. Traceability. Unique ID per part/reel from the supplier to guarantee the supply chain. This is then followed up with their own OE so the exact parts going into their goods.
2. Temperature tested.  -55C --> +125C

Comment: Seems like it's mostly #1 then, since, at least on digikey, the temperature range appears identical. Does the shape of the capacitor have anything to do with it? The MIL ones are square, where most others are more rounded.

Comment: you are right that #1 is the primary difference, #2 is an additional demand on military parts. The part packaging is a by and by. What you will find is military parts are usually "guaranteed" to be purchasable for 25years+ hence some old package types that modern commercial designs would not consider

Comment: *"guaranteed" to be purchasable for 25years+* | hence the lead-containing MIL vs. lead-free non MIL caps, I presume. Makes sense, thanks for clarifying things.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things the military needs, and numerous specs that you can google and look through if you desire but it boils down to these things:
1) Higher temperature ratings than standard industrial parts
2) Better Packaging (for IC's to withstand harsher environmental conditions)
3) More tolerance to EMI (where applicable)
4) Tracability (don't want your enemy to build weaknesses into your parts)

Comment: And some lead in their solder, please...

Comment: Hey for aerospace its important. You wouldn't want a 100M$ satellite to fail or a plane to go down because of a tin whisker.

Comment: They still use lead-free and plastic packaging in mil. As long as it meets the environment (they usually dip lead-free parts). Specialist parts can be rad hardened but these arnt usually sold to the general public. Large geometry are usually preferred for SEU immunity like APA FPGAs

Comment: Generally the packaging is different

Answer (score -1):

Lead is contained in solder coating of wires, many industrial and Mil have lead in solder because of older standards and lower soldering temperatures. Anyway Mil components are much more reliable than std components.

Comment: That isn't why Leaded solder is still permitted within Medical, Military, Aerospace. Lookup CAF, Tin Whiskers and the rigidity of lead-free.